# Vagrant Laravel setup, no input file specified

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am trying to setup homestead and laravel on a vagrant box. I get the error 'no input file specified' when I browse to my url:

http://homestead.app/, I have this setup in my hosts file `192.168.10.10 homestead.app`

My current `Homestead.yaml` file is located in `c:/users/me/Homestead` and looks like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Sites/Homestead_Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

WHen I run `vagrant up` I get this message:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> homestead-7: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
PS C:\Users\me\Homestead>
```

My project files I would like to be stored in, `C:\sites\Homestead_Projects` this is empty at the moment.

Can anyone advise how I can get my laravel site up and running?

My Virtualbox states homestead is running

[image]

`Git bash` shows homestead installed:

[image]

I also have a basic laravel site installed in my local folder:

[image]

Where do I install `Laravel` and how can I get a basic site setup?

Here is my powershell when I reload:

```
  PS C:\Users\Becky\Homestead> vagrant reload --provision
==> homestead-7: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
==> homestead-7: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead-7: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> homestead-7: Setting hostname...
==> homestead-7: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead-7: /vagrant => C:/Users/Becky/Homestead
    homestead-7: /home/vagrant/Sites => C:/sites/Homestead_Projects
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: file...
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/Becky/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20171016-6452-167i9e9.sh
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Certificate: homestead.app
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Site: homestead.app
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database: homestead
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database: homestead
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Update Composer
==> homestead-7: You are already using composer version 1.5.2 (stable channel).
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/Becky/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20171016-6452-196tg7e.sh
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/Becky/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20171016-6452-1v1vhk.sh
PS C:\Users\Becky\Homestead>
```

Comment: map: homestead.app

Answer (score 0):

Your site should be homestead.app instead of homestead.localhost. in your Homestead.yaml file, or reversed for the hosts file. Try to change it and then run vagrant provision!

**EDIT**

Apply the following changes :

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

map: C:/Sites
  to: /home/vagrant/Sites
```

Comment: After changing you should run `vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: exactly! forgot to mention it!

Comment: still get same error, Ive added my powershell messages above

Comment: Can you update the question, to the current situation with changes made?

Comment: Updated my yaml file.

Comment: in git bash, I cannot find the location `/home/vagrant/code/laravel/public` where should that be?